# Linear Regression of Time-Series Data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that is indexed by a monthly time stamp with numerous columns. The values of the dataframe are float64 and I simply would like to do a linear regression to calculate the slope of the data and store it as a new row at the bottom of the dataframe.

I have tried using linregress and polyfit but I cannot get the correct output, I either run into a unsupported operand type or SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'123': ['20.908', '8.743', '8.34', '2.4909'],
                 '124': ["2", 2.34, 0, 4.1234],
                  '412': ["3", 20.123, 3.123123, 0],
                   '516': ["5", 20.123, 3.123123, 0],
                   '129': ["10", 20.123, 3.123123, 0]},

                 index=['2015-01-10', '2015-02-10', '2015-03-10', '2015-04-10'])
```

Y would be the values in the column and X would be the time stamps in this case.

```
   123     124      412      516      129
2015-01-10  20.908       2        3        5       10
2015-02-10   8.743    2.34   20.123   20.123   20.123
2015-03-10    8.34       0  3.12312  3.12312  3.12312
2015-04-10  2.4909  4.1234        0        0        0
```

The expected output is that for each column, a linear fit is done and the slope of each column is added to a new row at the bottom.

Comment: To be clear, for each column what is your response variable?

Comment: Y for each column is the values in the column and X is always the timestamps that are the index row.

Comment: Did you check the types of your columns? Looks like you might have imported them as Objects.

Comment: dtypes are all float64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code should give you the idea:

```
df = df.astype(float)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
slopes = []
for col in df:
    x = df.index.month.values
    y = df[col].values
    b = (len(x) * (x * y).sum() - (x.sum() * y.sum())) / (len(x) * (x ** 2).sum() - x.sum() ** 2)
    slopes.append(b)
```

Slopes:
[-5.565429999999997,
 0.40302000000000004,
 -2.5999877,
 -3.1999877,
 -4.699987700000003]

The equations for linear regression are:

[image]

[source](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/probability-and-statistics/regression-analysis/find-a-linear-regression-equation/)

#### or with [numpy.polyfit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html)

```
df = df.astype(float)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
x = df.index.month.values
y = df.values
slopes, offsets = np.polyfit(x, y, deg=1)
```

Slopes: array([-5.56543  ,  0.40302  , -2.5999877, -3.1999877, -4.6999877])

Comment: Should there not be a way to do this with a lambda using a prebuilt function from scikit learn or another library?